# Vue dynamic child and sub-child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I have **Address.vue** component that contain child component **Contact.vue**.

`One address container many component`

> What I have done:

I have created the **Address.vue** component can increase dynamically so user can press **Add new address** and he will have as many addresses as he wants.

Also in the **Address.vue** component user can add multiple **Contacts** as much as he want.

So lets say the relation here is `1 address can have multiple contacts` and also the user can add multiple addresses.

I have done this UI and everything works perfectly.

> What I am trying to do:

Save the contact of each address in a `JSON Array` for example:

```
values: [
{
  address: {
    location: "Any location", 
    contacts: [{
      name: "Contact One",
      phone_number: "12345"
    }]
  }
},
{
  address: {
    location: "another location", 
    contacts: [
      {
        name: "Contact 3",
        phone_number: "6789"
      },
      {
        name: "Contact 4",
        phone_number: "101010"
      },
    ]
  }
},
]
```

> What I have done:

I have stored the **contacts array** in the **Contact.vue** component in an array and made an event to send data from the child component **(Contact.vue)** to the parent component **(Address.vue)**.

Then I got the **contacts array** from the event created in the **Address.vue** component

> Problem:

I can't refer **contacts** to the parent **address** as in the JSON structure mentioned above.

Comment: please explain these points * and created an event ..* and *I can't set the child Contacts to the parent Address in a JSON Array*

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim ok I will edit the question

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim kindly check the question now. I hope it is more clear now

Comment: so i understand that you get the contacts array in the address component, but i can't understand your problem could explain more or provide a tried code

Comment: I want to assign the contacts to the address as in the `JSON` that I have mentions

Comment: please provide address.vue code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I am understanding properly your problem:

**Note: If you create the Contacts vue component within the Address vue component. Vue will assigned each contact to its parent address.**

Ex:

Address.vue

```
<contact :id="this.count"></contact>
```

If Contacts.vue are created within Address.vue then in Address.vue:

Then in Andress.vue you can create an object or array element:

```
data(){
  return{
     location: "Any location"
     contacts:[]
  }
}
```

Then create a function saveContacts:

```
methods: {
  saveContacts(event, contact){
     this.contacts.push(contact);
  }
}
```

And finally when you check the event call the function :

```
@addedContact="saveContact($event,contact)"
```

This way you will have all addresses with its own contacts. More or less what you showed in your comment.

Hope this can be helpful to you.

Comment: The problem is that the `Address.vue` component itself is dynamic.. user can add multiple **addresses**.

Comment: True, but how do you make it dynamic? If you add dynamicaly Addresses adding more Addresses components each component it will have its own contacts. Ex: <address :id="this.count"></address><address :id="this.count"></address>